# Overloading operator= for custom types within class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have implementated a class for an arbitrary model as the following

```
class model_lincommands : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...

private:
    QList<lin_display_role> datalist_display_roles_;
    QList<LIN_FRAME> datalist_frames_;
    QList<LIN_CMD> datalist_commands_;
};
```

Furthermore, I have one custom struct/class, called `LIN_FRAME`, which is defined separately.

My goal is now depending on the typed cast to overload the `=`-operator and realize a handy copy function for **datalist_frames_**, which is from type `QList<LIN_FRAME>`.

In the `model_lincommands`, I have tried the following:

```
inline QList<LIN_FRAME> operator= (QList<LIN_FRAME> const& rhs)
{
    return this->datalist_frames_;
}
```

and then calling this by

```
QList<LIN_FRAME> tframe = *model;
```

whereas `*model` is a pointer to the instantiated `model_lincommands` class.

However, this is not working at all. Can you help me out what is the wrong point here?

Comment: What exact does not work?

Comment: Doesn't `QList<LIN_FRAME> tframe = *model;` refer to the rather copy constructor than the assignment operator?

Comment: @vahancho it is not copying. It's simple operator overloading. `*model` is not child of `QTableModel`.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator overloading is incorrect. Try `datalist_frames_ = rhs; return *this;` instead of `return this->datalist_frames_;` **Edited**

Comment: This gives the following error: `C:\AE\04_Code\TableWidgets2\Model_DndLinBatch.h:87: error: 'const class QList<LIN_FRAME>' has no member named 'datalist_frames_'`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What type has `model_lincommands`? It should be `QList<LIN_FRAME>`. In other cases - check signature of your operator overloading.

Comment: Note, i fixed my answer, there were a typo.

Comment: The semantics of C - hence C++ require that the value of the assignment operator be an l-value. References have that property, r-values don't. Hence a reference should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
// Operator overloading in C++
//assignment operator overloading
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
int idNum;
double salary;
public:
Employee ( ) {
    idNum = 0, salary = 0.0;
}

void setValues (int a, int b);
void operator= (Employee &emp );

};

void Employee::setValues ( int idN , int sal )
{

salary = sal; idNum = idN;

}

void Employee::operator = (Employee &emp)  // Assignment operator overloading function
{
salary = emp.salary;
}

int main ( )
{

Employee emp1;
emp1.setValues(10,33);
Employee emp2;
emp2 = emp1;        // emp2 is calling object using assignment operator

}
```

you can define your operator function inside the class, as you wish...